# docker change Ctrl+p to something else?

Tags: docker

I am using `docker run /bin/bash` to develop my container and every time I want to use `Ctrl+p` in a terminal or in emacs, I have to type it twice, since docker uses it to detach from a container (`Ctrl+p` `Ctrl+q`).

How can I change `Ctrl+p` to something else more convenient that is not used in emacs or in a terminal setting?

Comment: I was scratching my head for days trying to figure out why I couldn't go to the previous command line history in bash.  Truly an unfortunate choice of escape key bindings.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

[Docker has a configuration file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#configuration-files) and you can change the detach binding by adding

```
{
    "detachKeys": "ctrl-z,z"
}
```

to `~/.docker/config.json`.

If there are other entries in `config.json` then just add the "detachKeys" entry as the last one. For example:

```
{
    "HttpHeaders": {
        "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/19.03.11 (linux)"
    },
    "detachKeys": "ctrl-z,z"
}
```

**Note:** If you are running docker using `sudo docker ...` the `.docker` directory with the configuration file must be in the root's home directory (i.e., `/root/.docker/config.json`).

Comment: I was more thinking about a configuration file as it does not impact the actual behavior of a container, but I guess it works as well via commandline :). Anyhow, it is nice to have it finally.

Comment: @creack - this is longer the correct answer. See Brendan's answer below (or the PR: https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/15666). Please remove or update this answer).

Comment: This works for me - the answer is slightly confusing inasmuch as you simply need to ensure that this key-value pair is added to whatever the existing json body is in `config.json`.

Comment: Why don't you use `"detachKeys": "ctrl-e,e"`?

Comment: Ctrl-z is a good choice.  Wonder why they chose Ctrl-P.

Comment: How can I do this in podman?

Answer (score 24):

There is now a solution to this so thought I would update it here for others' convenience.

Just add a `~/.docker/config.json` and set your own keybinding.

```
{
    "detachKeys": "ctrl-e,e"
}
```

Now you can use `Ctrl-p` in bash and emacs again.  Yeah!

Comment: Doesn't work with `docker-compose`: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3311

Comment: That would make `ctrl+e` glitchy though. I wonder, is there a way to remove that combination altogether?

Answer (score 5):

Here's what worked for me (with a bit more detail than the other answers)

You modify the docker config file:

```
~/.docker/config.json
```

For example:

```
{
    "auths": {
            "amz": {
                "auth": key"
            },
            "amz2": {
                "auth": key2"
            },
            "amz3": {
                "auth": "key3" }
         },
    "detachKeys": "ctrl-e,e"
}
```

NOTE: the detach is no longer ctrl-p,ctrl-q, but rather ctrl-e + e key.

So the steps are:

1. Change the config file
2. Detach from the terminal (using the old/default key bindings)
3. Attach again (docker exec -it  /bin/bash

Subsequently the new keybindings that you specified should work

Source:
https://github.com/mx4492/dotfiles/commit/bad340b8ddeda6078093e89acacfcba8af74a0cc

Comment: I was wondering what I needed to do for docker to pick up the new config. Thanks for the extra detail.

Answer (score 5):

To use this without changing global configuration

```
docker exec --detach-keys='ctrl-e,e' -ti foo /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 4):

If anyone still can't get `Ctrl-P` to work inside a container even after changing the detach keys and calling `Ctrl-P` just prints out `^P` in the terminal instead of going up an entry in your history, make sure the shell you're using in the container can actually handle the process signals.

E.g. instead of `docker run -it ... sh`.

Use `docker run -it ... bash`.

Comment: Also, if you start container with '-a' option to attach to it and image uses CMD in exec mode then you're done because there is no shell running that can handle process signals. You will see '^P'. Must do ctrl-c to stop it and start container again without '-a' option.