# How to modify Docker configuration file in Kubernetes to resolve "Ctrl+p" keys?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

ctrl+p is commonly used as up arrow, however same combination is the detach sequence for docker. This need to be configured in the coniguration file

```
.docker/config.json
```

as described here 
[docker change Ctrl+p to something else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828657/docker-change-ctrlp-to-something-else)

How do we configure these keys when using kubernetes ?

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes has no such operation, all containers run in the background. You can connect in but it’s always still running the same way.

Comment: Is there away to pass the configuration when I connect to the container ? that is possible with pure docker.

Comment: What kind of configuration do you mean?

Comment: As I said, that is not a thing in kubernetes. All containers always run in the background, always.